# dtx file and history

Tags: glossaries, sorting, dtx

The `\changes` command of DTX file is used to record changes.

The `\PrintChanges` command print the list of change, sorted by number ... except when a number is greater than 10.

To see the problem, I invite you to read the change in the documentation of the `eledmac` package. You can see:

- v0.1
- v0.10
- v0.11
- ...
- v0.18
- v0.2

But the version 0.2 should be after v0.1.

I tried some technics with the `@` (like in index), but I could'nt solve this problem.

Comment: A ! why not ! for the change history, it's not problematic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Makeindex also supports sort keys. Entries of `\changes` or sorted with the style file `gglo.ist`. There the `actual char` is `=`:

```
\changes{v0.1=v0.001}...
\changes{v0.2=v0.001}...
...
\changes{v0.10=v0.010}...
\changes{v0.123=v0.123}...
```

This can also be automated, if `\changes` is redefined in the driver file:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable{\org@changes@}{%
  \let\org@changes@\changes@
  \@ifdefinable{\my@changes}{%
    \def\my@changes v#1.#2\@nil{%
      \org@changes@{v#1.\six@digits{#2}=v#1.#2}%
    }%
    \newcommand*{\six@digits}[1]{%
      \ifnum#1<100000 0\fi
      \ifnum#1<10000 0\fi
      \ifnum#1<1000 0\fi
      \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
      \two@digits{#1}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\changes@}[1]{%
      \my@changes#1\@nil
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Then you can continue with

```
\changes{v0.1}...
\changes{v0.2}...
\changes{v0.10}...
\changes{v0.123}...
```

For other numbering scheme `\my@changes` needs to be adopted.

Comment: thank a lot ! it's working https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/commit/4592be0

Answer (score 4):

By far the easiest thing is to number your minor version (retrospectively if necessary) as v0.01... which means that you are OK so long as you don't have 100 minor versions before the next major version.